# Need to show popup page when clicked the link

Tags: javascript, php

```
//function
function maps(url) {    
   window.open(url, "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500,width=400, height=400");
}
```

php page

```
 $display.= "<td><a  href='#' onclick='maps('google.com')'>"visit "</a></td>";
```

I have checked the function without passing url variable and it works but when i used url varibale its not working. I want this function to use everywhere.

help me

Comment: Don't use `onclick`, instead look up some of the Unobtrusive JavaScript principles. In your case give the link a class and rather attach an `onclick` event handler for all links that have the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in concatenate the url string inside function. 
Try to give it inside `\"`.

And give `absolute url` as parameter.

```
$display = "<td><a href='#' onclick='maps(\"http://www.google.com\");'>Visit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this once..

change

```
onclick='maps('google.com')'

to

onclick='maps(\'google.com\')'
```

Answer (score 0):

you are concatenating the string in wrong way .use the code below it will work

```
$display= "<td><a  href='#' onclick=\"maps('google.com')\">visit</a></td>";
```